# Robust solution to dynamically transform SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-transitions

Apparently, IE10 does not support CSS `transform`ations for SVGs, only attribute transformations like so ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R4Ca5/)):

```
<svg><rect id="myrect" width="200" height="200"></rect></svg>
```

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    var r = document.getElementById("myrect")

    //works in IE
    //r.setAttribute("transform","scale(1.5)")   

    //does not work in IE
    r.style.transform = r.style.WebkitTransform = "scale(1.5)"
},1000);
```

Where supported, I want to include a smooth transition:

```
#myrect { transition: all 1s; }
```

The way I see it, a smooth transitions requires a CSS transformation, whereas IE requires an attribute transformation.

So what's the best strategy? Test for IE, then if IE use an attribute transformation, else use a CSS transformation?

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: You should use `transform` instead of `WebkitTransform` (or both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do the animation in javascript with IE e.g.

```
var scale = 1;

function f()
    {
        var r = document.getElementById("myrect")

        //works in IE
        r.setAttribute("transform","scale(" + scale + ")")

        scale += 0.001;

setTimeout(f, 10);
    };

setTimeout(f, 10);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/bVkaF/)

This will work on other UAs too but you could use SMIL or CSS transforms with those instead.